# Intersection of two lists in NetLogo

Tags: list, netlogo, set-intersection

I need to calculate the size of the intersection of two lists in NetLogo. Here is my working example:

```
to calculate-intersection
ask turtles
 [ set first-list ( list turtles-on link-neighbors )
   foreach first-list <br>
    [ set second-list ( list turtles-on link-neighbors )
      set intersection intersection + count ( first-list with [ member? self second-list ] )]]
end
```

I have a network and I want to know how many of the nodes A is linked to are also linked between themselves. That is:

In a network of 5 nodes: **A**, **B**, **C**, **D** and **E**:

1. Node A is linked to B C D E
2. Node B is linked to D
3. Node D is linked to B

Then I want intersection for `Node A = 2`

I have tried many different ways unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 2):

I think this shows what you are asking for.

```
ask turtles [ 
  let nbrs1 link-neighbors
  show sum [count other nbrs1 with [link-neighbor? myself]] of nbrs1
]
```

You might be able to gain some efficiency using `nw:with-context`.  (Maybe you could even use `nw:clustering-coefficient` instead?)

Comment: Is `other nw:turtles-in-radius 1` equivalent to `link-neighbors`?

Comment: According to the documentation yes: https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension#turtles-in-radius-turtles-in-reverse-radius

Comment: By the way, `nw:with-context` won't help here. It's there for the particular case in which you either need to temporarily analyze a different network, or you have multiple forever buttons operating on different networks. It doesn't help with performance. Staying in one context does help with performance though.

`nw:clustering-coefficient` should definitely be faster (not to mention more succinct). If it isn't, report it so we can fix it!